# C/STM32 structure pointer

Tags: c

I've been working with stm32f103, now I'm trying to lunch some codes on stm32f407.
To communicate through USART interface I use fifo query in form of structure, defined in header file:

```c
#define FIFO_BUF_SIZE           128

typedef struct {
    char data[FIFO_BUF_SIZE];
    uint16_t startIndex;
    uint16_t endIndex;
}FIFO, *ptrFIFO;
```

Global declaration of this structure in source file:

```c
FIFO RX_Buff={{},0,0};
FIFO TX_Buff={{},0,0};
```

Now I want to put data from char array to fifo query:

```c
void USART_PrintData(USART_TypeDef * USART, char str[]){
    ptrFIFO pTX = &TX_Buff;
    int i=0;

    while(str[i]!='\0'){
         FIFO_Put(pTX, str[i]);
         i++;
    }
        //here in working program is code for sending data
        //deleted from program for tests
}

void FIFO_Put(ptrFIFO fifo, char data){
    uint16_t tmp;
    tmp = fifo->startIndex;
    fifo->data[tmp]=data;
    tmp = (tmp+1)%(FIFO_BUF_SIZE-1);
    fifo->startIndex=tmp;
}
```

This code has been worked on stm32f103 but won't on f407. After last sign passed to FIFO_Put() and write to fifo query, programm go to Default_Handler or strange address in memory (depends of humor), but when I using this structure directly it works fine:

```c
void FIFO_Put(char data){
    uint16_t tmp;
    tmp = TX_Buff.startIndex;
    TX_Buff.data[tmp]=data;
    tmp = (tmp+1)%(FIFO_BUF_SIZE-1);
    TX_Buff.startIndex=tmp;
}
```

I have no idea what's wrong.

Thanks for any help.

---

I've tried to debug, and the problem is in last line in function FIFO_Put():

```
fifo->startIndex=tmp;
```

When function putting last sign to fifo, after last line program jump to default_handler.
If I comment this line, program works fine.

Comment: Looks okay to me. Can you attach it to a debugger?

Comment: Maybe this is stack size problem?

Comment: Thank You! it was the problem. My project based on templates from this site: http://www.freddiechopin.info/. In linker script was two stacks: main stack and process stack. Size of the first was set on 0, when i reset on 1024 program began to work. I wonder why there are two stacks?

Comment: Have no idea, just a guess based on some experience with TA products... I post this as answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the program stack size - from my experience, such kind of undefined behavior may be caused by stack overflow.